# Gregorian Calendar - Getting wrong values in Android

Tags: java, android, date, gregorian-calendar

I am using Gregorian calendar to set the date value and trying to get the values set. Code below

```
 Constants.sSetDate_calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day);// year - 2013, month - 12, day - 15
          Log.w("OOOOO", Constants.sSetDate_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"--"+Constants.sSetDate_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"--"+Constants.sSetDate_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"");
```

In Log statement, i see

```
11-02 10:21:35.060: W/OOOOO(26671): **2014--0--15**
```

Not sure what is going wrong.  Why the values set and get are different ?
Need some help here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure months are zero-based so January is 0 and December is 11. By specifying month as 12 you're adding a year to your expected date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Calendar class uses a zero-based array meaning January is `0` and December is `11` as can be seen by looking at the [Calendar.JANUARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) and [Calendar.DECEMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DECEMBER) values. The 12th month simply overflows into the next year (December + 1 month) which is why the values change.